# yii : CGridView filter dropdown from controller array

Tags: php, yii

Q : How to filter CGridview filter dropdown from controller array

I create an array at my controller

```
$arr_method = array('Cash'=>'Cash', 'Cheque'=>'Cheque', 'Credit Card'=>'Credit Card', 'Bank Transf'=>'Bank Transf');
```

I call above array at Cgridview

```
array('name' => 'method',
               'value'=>'(isset($data->method)) ? CHtml::encode($data->method) :""',
               'filter'=>CHtml::dropDownList('method', '', $arr_method),
        ),
```

dropdown list is appear at filter. but when I select something, filter is going back to 'Cash'. and result is showing blank.

Comment: what are the actual values of `method` in your db? although mike could also be right

Comment: in DB, method is ENUM ('Cash',.....)

Comment: you'll have to do some debugging with firebug, check if the data is being sent, and see what data is being received, on selection of the value

Comment: this param : AccPaymentRecei[acc_categ... 
AccPaymentRecei[acc_recei... 
AccPaymentRecei[date] 
AccPaymentRecei[descripti... 
AccPaymentRecei[method] Cash
AccPaymentRecei_page 1
ajax acc-payment-recei-grid

Comment: received : html page with result is NULL.

Comment: ok, and are the other filters working fine? see your controller's action, there is definitely something wrong there then

Comment: Thx bool.dev. I moved to filter by date range. Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use the dropdownlist function just use

```
'filter'=>$arr_method
```

Comment: looking good. dropdown is appear easily. but the result is showing blank as before.